# How to hide DWR class index?

Tags: dwr

DWR publishes some index of classes under `[context root]/dwr/`. The index contains links to more details about the services. This seems like information leakage to me and I would like to hide/unpublish these pages so they are not accesible.

How can I configure DWR to hide this class index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great pentesting blog that talks about it here: http://gerionsecurity.com/2012/09/experiences-in-pentesting-dwr/

Essentially you disable debugging in in web.xml when you configure the servlet.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>debug</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```